# Apply or outer functions without loops

Tags: r, loops, outer-join

```
A = function(j,x){
  if(x<0 & x>j){stop(print(1))}
   else{
     s=0
     for(k in 0:x){
      s = s + ((j-1) * ((2)^k) * x)
    }
  }
 return(s)
}
```

On a side note, does anyone know how to NOT use loops and use functions like outer or apply to run this?

Comment: Can you explain in words what your code is doing ?

Comment: "on a side note" what was the main note?

Comment: anyway, this looks like a geometric sum, for which there is a closed form. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series

Comment: Sorry typed it in a hurry because I had to do something else.

essentially a(j, x) is just a summation equation. So, if j = 3 and we have a vector of x's like c(1, 2, 3) I'd want to be able to print out a list of values the summed values without having to use a `for` loop to read the vector x or the k values

Comment: Please use the edit button to add relevant information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:?

```
j <- 2
x <- 2

A(j, x)
# [1] 14

A2  <- function(j, x){
  if(x<0 & x>j) {
    stop(print(1))
    } else {
      s <- sum((j-1) * 2^(0:x) * x)
  }
  return(s)
}

A2(j, x)
# [1] 14
```